# How to update local repository location in tower?

Tags: macos, location, repository, mamp-pro, git-tower

I have updated my MAMP PRO application from 5.7 to 6.4. Now all the project document roots changed from "/Application/MAMP/htdocs/" to "/Sites/" directory.

I moved all projects into "/Sites/" director now all projects were installed properly. But now the issue is I can't change the git tower local repository location in "Tower" application.

[image]

Is this possible to change the local repository location in tower application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tower does not offer a specific "relocate" feature. The reason behind this is that it is very easy to simply remove the repository (right-click on the repository then select Delete) and then re-add it by dragging and dropping it to the repository view from Finder.

In any case, adding a specific option for this is on our list of things to do, happy to add your vote to this feature request!